# Ошибка в описании шляпы

Tags: дефект, локализация, новогодние-шляпы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну "в течение" же!

---

*И формулировка "ответьте верно" не совсем верна. Ответ не должен быть "верным", он должен быть принятыми. "Верным" ему при этом быть совсем необязательно.*